# Hive: Partitioning by part of integer column

Tags: hive

I want to create an external Hive table, partitioned by record type and date (year, month, day). One complication is that the date format I have in my data files is a single value integer yyyymmddhhmmss instead of the required date format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.
Can I specify 3 new partition column based on just single data value? Something like the example below (which doesn't work)

```
create external table cdrs (
record_id int, 
record_detail tinyint,
datetime_start int
)
partitioned by (record_type int, createyear=datetime_start(0,3) int, createmonth=datetime_start(4,5) int, createday=datetime_start(6,7) int)
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '|' 
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as TEXTFILE
location 'hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/sbx_unleashed.db'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1", "skip.footer.line.count"="1");
```

Comment: Partitioning will have meaning here only if your HDFS data is already separated to different directories by record_type and datetime_start (or variation on it). Is that the case?

Comment: It isn't yet. So if I understand you correctly then I need to make directories of the following form: hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/sbx_unleashed.db/createyear=2017/createmonth=01/createday=01/recordtype=1, then physically move the files to the appropriate hdfs directory, and then run the command above with 'partioned by (createyear int, createmonth int, createday int, record_type int)?

Comment: Why not just using a date for the partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to use `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` to add the partition for you based on the directories structure you should use the following convention:

- The nesting of the directories should match the order of the partition columns.
- A directory name should be `{partition column name}={value}`

---

If you intends to add the partitions manually then the structure has no meaning.
Any set values can be coupled with any directory. e.g. -

```
alter table cdrs  
add if not exist partition (record_type='TYP123',createdate=date '2017-03-22') 
location 'hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/sbx_unleashed.db/2017MAR22_OF_TYPE_123';
```

---

Assuming directory structure -

```
.../sbx_unleashed.db/record_type=.../createyear=.../createmonth=.../createday=.../
```

e.g.

```
.../sbx_unleashed.db/record_type=TYP123/createyear=2017/createmonth=03/createday=22/
```

---

```
create external table cdrs 
(
   record_id      int
  ,record_detail  tinyint
  ,datetime_start int
)
partitioned by (record_type int,createyear int, createmonth tinyint, createday tinyint)
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '|' 
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as TEXTFILE
location 'hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/sbx_unleashed.db'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1", "skip.footer.line.count"="1")
;
```

Assuming directory structure -

```
.../sbx_unleashed.db/record_type=.../createdate=.../
```

e.g.

```
.../sbx_unleashed.db/record_type=TYP123/createdate=2017-03-22/
```

---

```
create external table cdrs 
(
   record_id      int
  ,record_detail  tinyint
  ,datetime_start int
)
partitioned by (record_type int,createdate date)
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '|' 
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as TEXTFILE
location 'hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/sbx_unleashed.db'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1", "skip.footer.line.count"="1")
;
```

Comment: Works like a charm. However for others reading this answer, keep in mind that your table will still be empty. Run "ALTER TABLE cdrs ADD PARTITION (createyear = '2017', createmonth='01', createday='01');" afterwards for each partition to make the data show up.

Comment: If you are following convention, you only need to execute `MSCK REPAIR TABLE cdrs`, this will modify all partitions (add + drop) according to the directories structure